# How to pass special character through cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I want to save username & password in my google-sheet and I am able to pass these info through cURL with below code:

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
if (!empty($value) && !is_null($value)) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
 } else {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=-&';
 }
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$gResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

But having trouble when have the special character in password field.
Because user can use any special character including '&' charcater and when this '&' character is used cURL defined as a different string

Is there any possible ways to get rid of this issue ?

Comment: Do you get the same issue using wp_remote_post() function?

Comment: actually this is raw PHP code. I am not using WP :(

Comment: `$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);`

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP function urlencode();

Example:

```
 $new_url = urlencode($url);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can i urldecode during save in googlesheet ? I want to save the exact password in sheet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing to StackOverflow. This answer would better fit the [guidelines for good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) if you included, e.g., a brief code sample demonstrating how to solve the question with the `urlencode()` function.

Comment: @MehediHasan  It's actually each value in your post string that needs to be url encoded.  `$fields_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';`